# why this NIntegrate doesn't work?

Tags: numerical-integration

I intend to run a `NIntegrate` inside a `Do` loop. At first I import the integrand as a txt file and then number it using loop number because I need them after exiting the loop. But when I run the code it can't specify the integrand. I can't write all my code here, but a toy example can be

```
Do[
f[i] = x^2 + 3 y;
 ans = NIntegrate[f[i], {x, 0, 10}];
 Print[ans]
 , {i, 1, 2}]

(*NIntegrate[f[i],{x,0,10}]
NIntegrate[f[i],{x,0,10}]
*)
```

As you can see the printed results show that the code failed to specify the `f[1]` and `f[2]` correctly. How can deal with this problem?

**Addendum**

this is the simple scheme of my code

[image]

Note that the `fCorrHFE[mp]` is a function itself and I will plot it in the next step.

Comment: Please paste minimal code. The `Do` loops will run but the loop variables won't be advancing?? `Do[expr, {i, imax}]` should be the syntax, i think?

Comment: I know, but as I said this is just a scheme to understand my code

Comment: Did you run the code in my preliminary answer, where does it not work for you? Assuming that your integrand is now an expression and that it has limits supplied to it, what is the error now? When you import a file, does it have one integrand per file?

Comment: Sorry but I don't understand how your code can solve the problem? Note that the answer of numerical integration is a function itself and I will supply the remained limit in plot command

Comment: I don't understand how the `NIntegrate` will give you a function but then I don't understand a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a comment about how to create an MWE from the addendum in this specific case.  Currently the addendum cannot be executed because it depends on unavailable files.

One can mimic reading a group of files with `Association`. One should only imitate a ***minimal number*** of files.  Arguably it's 2 or 4 in this case (test distinct values for `mp` and `w`/omega).  It's important that the mock expressions for the file contents have the same variables as in the real case.  I would say you can use a simpler expression; problems with `NIntegrate` converging should be asked as a separate question, where the actual integrand will be needed.

In the loop, I did nothing to fix the inherent problems with the code. I did merge the nested `Do` loops.  The role of `Import` is performed by the association `readFile`. I treated the integrand as a temporary variable, but `integrand[mp]` can be used if desired.

```
readFile = Association@Flatten@Table[ (* imports fake data *)
     StringTemplate["gE_m=`1`-w=`2`.txt"][mp, w] ->
      StringTemplate["`1` x+y^`2`"][mp, w],
     {mp, 2}, {w, 2}];

Do[
 filename = StringTemplate["gE_m=`1`-w=`2`.txt"][mp, w];
 integrand = ToExpression@readFile[filename];
 fCorrHFE[mp] = NIntegrate[integrand, {x, 0, 20}];,
 {w, 2}, {mp, 2}]
```

The above does not address any of the problems in the OP:

- `NIntegrate` evaluates on an expression that is not numeric when `x` equals a number.
- `fCorrHFE[mp]` does not depend on `w`, so that all the values for `w = 1` are overwritten in the next iteration of the `Do[]` loop.
- `fCorrHFE[mp]` represents an expression that depends on `y`, every time `fCorrHFE[mp]` is evaluated, `NIntegrate` will give errors unless `y` has a numeric value at the time.

This addresses those problems:

```
Block[{NIntegrate},
 Do[
  filename = StringTemplate["gE_m=`1`-w=`2`.txt"][mp, w];
  integrand = ToExpression@readFile[filename];
  fCorrHFE[mp, w, y_?NumericQ] = NIntegrate[integrand, {x, 0, 20}],
  {w, 2}, {mp, 2}]
 ]
```

Suspending execution while constructing code to be evaluated later is one of the functions of `Block[]`.  The use of `=` instead of `:=` in the definition `fCorrHFE` allows `integrand` to be evaluated (since the attributes of `NIntegrate` are blocked as well as its execution).

Comment: Thank you very much for your detailed explanation and useful points, However it wasn't the exact answer of my question.

Answer (score 3):

- If the integrand is a string, use `ToExpression`.
- If the integrand has `x` and `y` as variables, supply the limits.

```
    Clear[x, y, i, f]
    Do[
     Echo[i];
     f[i] = ToExpression["x^2+3y"];
     Echo[f[i]];
     ans = NIntegrate[f[i], {x, 0, 10}, {y, 0, 10}];
     Print[ans], {i, 1, 2}
    ]
```

Comment: Please see my addendum

Answer (score 2):

> As you can see the printed results show that the code failed to specify the `f[1]` and `f[2]` correctly. How can deal with this problem?

I will interpret "correctly" to mean that you see `f[i]` and not either `x^2 + y` or `f[1]` etc.  Since `NIntegrate` has the attribute `HoldAll`, you need to either evaluate `f[i]` or inject `i`.

Evaluate:

```
ans = NIntegrate[Evaluate@f[i], {x, 0, 10}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Inject:

```
ans = With[{i = i}, NIntegrate[f[i], {x, 0, 10}]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

*Comment:*
This seems an [XY Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem) in which the real problem Y is kept from us in favor of problem X, because either the OP thinks problem Y is too complex and problem X captures the essence of Y or the OP is certain that solving problem X will allow them to solve Y.  But there are aspects of X that are inherently confusing. The expression `f[i]` is not really a function but indexed data; moreover, it's the same for every index `i`.  The addendum mentions that `ans`/`fCorrHFE[mp]` is itself a "function," although to experienced *Mathematica* users, it does not appear programmatically to be a function.  Presumably it is an expression that depends on uninitialized parameters.  In that case, `ans` might be defined something like the following. The exact usage is unclear in the OP, but the following avoids wasting time and a lot of error messages by not pointlessly evaluating `NIntegrate`. Be sure to `Clear[ans]` before the `Do` loop:

```
ans[i] = 
  Function[{y1, y2}, NIntegrate[#, {x, 0, 10}, {y, y1, y2}]] &[f[i]];
```

[image]

(Note that the evaluation approach is problematic in this case.  The integrand is too deep inside nested `HoldAll` functions for `Evaluate` to work.  Injection with `With[{i = i},...]` causes the arguments of `Function` to be rewritten `{y1$, y2$}`, which works as long as the expressions represented by `f[1]` etc. do not depend on `y1` or `y2`.)